# ExecuteStoreQuery syntax error in ef4

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Someone knows why this gives me incorrect syntax exception near @table?

```
object[] changeQueryParams = new object[] { new SqlParameter("table", dbContext.tXSell.EntitySet.Name), new SqlParameter("fromversion", 0) };

string changeQueryString = @"SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES @table, @fromversion) AS ch";

ObjectResult<object> changes = dbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<object>(changeQueryString, changeQueryParams);
```

I am useing mssql 2008 r2, ef4, c#.

Comment: Yep, you're right, someone knows!

Comment: Is `CHANGES` a keyword in Sql?  Try `string changeQueryString = @"SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(@table, @fromversion) AS ch";`

Comment: You can see the doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934145(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I need that `CHANGES` in there.

Comment: Why are you assigning your parameters to an array?  When you call them, you need to call them by the index they are located at; which you are not doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can't pass a table name to the [CHANGETABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934145.aspx) SQL function as a parameter. You can try to build your SQL dynamically. It should be safe from sql injection as you are only concatenating value from `EntitySet.Name` property.

```
string changeQueryString = @"SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES " + dbContext.tXSell.EntitySet.Name +" , @fromversion) AS ch";
```